Angular 17 (SSR) : Swiper
So that Angular doesn't generate an SSR error, I have to use isPlatformBrowser because ngSkipHydration doesn't work when I set it.
Only what I put in [config] isn't taken into account, do you know why?
Thanks
import {
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
    Component,
    ElementRef,
    OnInit,
    PLATFORM_ID,
    inject,
    signal,
    viewChild,
} from '@angular/core';

import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { SwiperContainer } from 'swiper/element';
import { SwiperOptions } from 'swiper/types';

@Component({
    selector: 'tk-images',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [],
    template: `
        <swiper-container #swiper [config]="options()">
            @for(image of data.data().home.images; track image) {
            <swiper-slide>
                <img [src]="image" alt="Image" />
            </swiper-slide>
            }
        </swiper-container>
    `,
    styles: `
    swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 8px;
      swiper-slide {
        img {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          object-fit: cover;
          border-radius: 8px;
        }
      }
    }
  `,
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class ImagesComponent implements OnInit {
    data = inject(DataService);
    platformId = inject(PLATFORM_ID);

    options = signal<SwiperOptions>({});
    swiper = viewChild<ElementRef<SwiperContainer>>('swiper');

    ngOnInit(): void {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
            this.options.set({
                loop: true,
                grabCursor: true,
                autoplay: {
                    delay: 100,
                    disableOnInteraction: false,
                },
            });

            this.swiper()?.nativeElement.initialize();
        }
    }
}


I just want a swiper with scrolling images. Loaded from a service that retrieves them from a backend.

I think you should bind init="false" in the swiper-container props as this prevents it from being created earlier

I have commented ngOnInit and put this : <swiper-container #swiper [init]="false">...
but swiper initializes anyway

oh okay i have put init without brackets and now it's not intialized, but it's doesnt care about my options...  : https://imgur.com/5JQYs7L

Do not comment ngOnInit and write like this: <swiper-container #swiper init="false">...

try this: this.swiper()?.nativeElement?.swiper.update()

Unfortunately, it doesn't work :( But I did it like this since I don't have many parameters... https://imgur.com/BXLRVfQ . Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!
